# applescript - how to access the clipboard as an iTunes track or file track object

Tags: applescript, clipboard, itunes

I'm trying to dev a custom paste script for iTunes. After 'copy'' of some playlist tracks, the user should call the script in stead of standard paste, to paste the tracks into another playlist. The script will do some extra stuff apart from pasting the tracks.

Question: To paste the clipboard as tracks an iTunes playlist I need to find the clipboard contents as Track class objects, not the file names, furl's or whatever.

```
clipboard info
```

says it has the following in the clipboard:

```
{
    {Unicode text, 776},
    {string, 388},
    {«class itun», 4036},
    {«class furl», 118},
    {«class ut16», 778}
}
```

Now, the class furl objects might point me to the files, but that still doesn't get me an iTunes "File Track" or a "Track".
Is there anyone who can shed some light on what the class "itun" things are which are on the clipboard? (Tried for a day to find out myself, but didn't get anywhere) And, whether itun class objects might be usable to get to the copied-to-the-clipboard tracks?

Comment: You asked "Is there anyone who can shed some light on what the class "itun" things are which are on the clipboard?", The clipboard object `«class itun»` contains an XML record of e.g. a copied track in `data` format, e.g. `«data itun3C3F786D6C2076657273696F6E3D22312E302220656E636F64696E673D225554462D38223F3E»`, i.e. `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>` Here's what the XML looks like for one copied track: https://paste.ee/p/zXIWd

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to do what you're asking using the clipboard. But why use the clipboard at all? If someone wants to "copy" the tracks this assumes that they have first selected the tracks. And if they have the tracks selected then there is no need to perform the copy step. A simple applescript can get the selection from iTunes so why not just use that approach? You get the selection as tracks and then do whatever you need in the rest of the applescript.

```
tell application "iTunes"
    set selectedTracks to the selection

    -- do whatever else you need
end tell
```